# change hyper link address from old domain to new domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i have uploaded my CodeIgniter website to another domain. i dont want my old domain anymore. problem is that i cant change manually every hyperlink from old to new
like
[www.oldedomain.com/home](http://www.oldedomain.com/home)
[www.oldedomain.com/about](http://www.oldedomain.com/about)

i want to change automatically all the pages link to new domain name
[www.newdomain.com/home](http://www.newdomain.com/home)
[www.newdomain.com/home](http://www.newdomain.com/home)

for all pages in website.
plz provide me best solution.

Comment: Sure. Sounds great. All you need is a redirection rule, Go !

Comment: Changing the actual link URLs that your system outputs in the HTML, is not done in .htaccess/on the web server level, you need to facilitate that within CI itself. URL rewriting helps with redirecting old, _external_ links to their new counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the base_url of your website in the config.php file of your codeigniter 3 config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.newdomain.com';
```

or you can use the following lines and it will automatically detect your domain:

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

If you are using CI4, use the following code in your Constants file:

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
defined('BASEURL') || define('BASEURL',$root);
```

and in your App.php file:

```
public $baseURL = BASEURL;
```

You will also have to change the server level config in your Apache/Nginx vhost files.